# How to switch database backends in Genie.jl if you already created an App?

Tags: julia, genie.jl

I am following this tutorial: https://genieframework.com/docs/tutorials/Developing-MVC-Web-Apps.html#gettingstarted-creatingtheapp where I created my MVC app and selected a MySQL backend. However, I am having issues with MySQL so I want to switch the app to SQLite as the tutorial uses. Is there any way I can switch the app to use that or would I have to manually re-create a new project? If I can switch it, what files need to be manually modified or is there a function that can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switch it manually, it's quite easy:

1/ add support for SQLite via `SearchLightSQLite`:

```
pkg> add SearchLightSQLite
```

2/ edit `db/connection.yml` and set `adapter` to `SQLite` and `database` to the path where you want to store the DB, ex:

```
dev:
  adapter: SQLite
  database: db/dev.sqlite
```

3/ Restart the app

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might face the same challenge,
You need to add SearchLightMySQL to the project by running Pkg add SearchLightMySQL